# HTML Parsing With AsyncTask makes the main thread slow

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am trying to download an HTML source and extracting a text in order to use it. But html is not well coded it's in a table and I couldn't think different way to extract it and I am using regex with pattern and matcher to extract it. I am doing download and parsing tasks 2 times. First task is doing great without any problem but when I try to do second task it skips the frames and saying you are doing too much on main thread but these operations in the AsyncTask. 
   *My AsyncDownload task*

```
public class DownloadTheCoursesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

*First parsing task which works perfectly*

```
public void getTheCourses() {
    DownloadTheCoursesTask coursesTask = new DownloadTheCoursesTask();
    String result = "";

    try {
        result = coursesTask.execute("http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php").get();
        coursesResult = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern firstPattern = Pattern.compile("<option  value=\"(.*?)\">");
        Matcher firstMatcher = firstPattern.matcher(result);

        while (firstMatcher.find()) {
            coursesResult.add(firstMatcher.group(1));
        }

    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*Second parsing task which crashes my app and says skipping frames*

```
public void getTheQuota(){
    DownloadTheCoursesTask quotaTask = new DownloadTheCoursesTask();
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = quotaTask.execute("http://www.sis.itu.edu.tr/tr/ders_programlari/LSprogramlar/prg.php?fb=BEB").get();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<html><head>(.*?)</html>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
        while (m.find()) {
            quotaResult.add(m.group(1));
        }

    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Many people says that use jSoup but my first task is running perfectly. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `.get()` member to execute an AsyncTask as then it will run on the main thread.

Do without and handle the result of `doInBackground()` in `onPostExecute()`.

So your first task is wrong already too.

Comment: Oh i didn't know that thank you.So i will remove the get and i will add parsing operation to onPostExecute  right ?

Comment: Well you should do time consuming operations in doInBackGround. So the parsing too.